# Best way to make a mid-stream forEach

Tags: java

I have a class

```
class MyDto{

...
boolean isPredicted;
...

}
```

And a List of it

```
List<MyDto> myDtoList = ....
```

I need to filter, sort and set isPredicted to false for each element. Actually my code is.

```
List<MyDto> myDtoList = service.getDtos()
 .filter(...)
 .sorted(...)
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My Idea was to place a "for each element set isPredicted to false", between sorted and collect.

```
List<MyDto> myDtoList = service.getDtos()
 .filter(...)
 .sorted(...)
 .peek(e->e.setPredicted(false))
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But after I read some resources on the internet, I think to use peek here is bad Idea. As it was build for Debug operations.

How I can avoid peek() here?

Comment: Why would you say it is a bad idea?

Comment: Please reformulate your post in terms of a definitively answerable question.  Asking for "a better way" leads to opinion-based answers which will be downvoted or removed.

Comment: reformulated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to separately loop and set your properties after collecting:

```
List<MyDto> myDtoList = service.getDtos()
 .filter(...)
 .sorted(...)
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
myDtoList.forEach(e -> e.setPredicted(false));
```

or stay in functional land and `map` to new objects:

```
List<MyDto> myDtoList = service.getDtos()
 .filter(...)
 .sorted(...)
 .map(e -> {
    final MyDto dto = new MyDto();
    dto.set...(e.get...());
    dto.set...(e.get...());
    dto.setPredicted(false);
    return dto;
 })
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Introducing a copy-constructor/factory or static copy-method can make your life and your code simpler.

Comment: `.map(e -> e.setPredicted(false))` wouldn't work ?

Comment: @Tom no, because `map` is defined as `map(Function<E, R>)` and must return the new elements of the stream. `setPredicated` is presumably void. Even it weren't, you wouldn't be streaming your original DTO elements anymore.